# MySQL INNODB_LOCK_WAITS empty

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to investigate if blocking is to blame for a performance issue we are experiencing.

MySQL version: 5.6.32-78.1

The following tables exist but are empty.

- INNODB_LOCKS
- INNODB_LOCK_WAITS

The information_schema.innodb_trx table has data in it.

Please can someone explain how to expose the data in the lock/lock_waits table? I have read an InnoDB plugin is required. Is this the case for 5.6? I was hoping to dynamically enable/disable capturing locking info.

Comment: Instead of starting there, let's start with the slowest query.  The slowlog is handy for finding such.

Comment: Thanks Rick.  I've taken a look at the slow log already.  I'm really interested in being able to see locks and lock_waits.  Do you have any idea how to enable the viewing of this data?  Thanks.

Comment: dba.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask your question.

Answer (score 0):

When the issue is happening, you may try executing query `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` to examine the lock waits.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-engine.html for more information.